# Aggregate distinct values in collections in SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a collection type in it.  I want to `SELECT` from the table and `GROUP BY` some column.  I want the results for each group to include a collection that contains the distinct union of all the individual collections in the group.

For example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_varchar2_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (80);

WITH test_data (id, a_list) AS
       (SELECT 1,
               NEW my_varchar2_list ('A', 'B', 'C')
        FROM   DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1,
               NEW my_varchar2_list ('C', 'D', 'E')
        FROM   DUAL)
SELECT id,
       ... some magic syntax here...
FROM   test_data
GROUP BY id

Desired results:

1,  ('A','B','C','D','E')
```

#### What I am looking for in an answer

I am only looking for expressions that I can plug into the "magic syntax goes here" placeholder above.  I know I can accomplish the aggregate by joining `TABLE(a_list)` to the main table or otherwise restructuring my query (or, of course, using PL/SQL). However, I want to avoid such solutions for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024964/1509264) to another question.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR2s_Table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/
```

Create a user-defined aggregation type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Varchar2sTableUnion AS OBJECT(
  list VARCHAR2s_Table,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion,
    value       IN     VARCHAR2s_Table
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion,
    returnValue    OUT VARCHAR2s_Table,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion,
    ctx         IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Varchar2sTableUnion
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := Varchar2sTableUnion( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion,
    value       IN     VARCHAR2s_Table
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF self.list IS NULL THEN
      self.list := value;
    ELSE
      self.list := self.list MULTISET UNION DISTINCT value;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion,
    returnValue    OUT VARCHAR2s_Table,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.list;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion,
    ctx         IN OUT Varchar2sTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.list IS NULL THEN
      self.list := ctx.list;
    ELSIF ctx.list IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      self.list := self.list MULTISET UNION DISTINCT ctx.list;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/
```

Create a user-defined aggregation function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MULTISET_UNION( list VARCHAR2s_Table )
RETURN VARCHAR2s_Table
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING Varchar2sTableUnion;
/
```

**Query**:

Then you can just use it to perform the aggregation in your query:

```
WITH test_data (id, a_list) AS
       (SELECT 1,
               varchar2s_table ('A', 'B', 'C')
        FROM   DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1,
               varchar2s_table ('C', 'D', 'E')
        FROM   DUAL)
SELECT id,
       MULTISET_UNION( a_list )
FROM   test_data
GROUP BY id
```

**Output**:

```
ID MULTISET_UNION(A_LIST)
-- -------------------------------------------
 1 SCHEMA.VARCHAR2S_TABLE('A','B','C','D','E')
```

Comment: Great!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!