# Create an EQUALS(...) function that accepts multiple datatypes?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-functions, sqldatatypes, oracle18c

As an experiment, I'm interested in writing a custom `equals(..)` function that would mimic the `is [not] distinct from` functionality that exists in some databases (but not Oracle).

> [NULL-Aware Comparison: `is \[not\] distinct from`](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/is-not-distinct-from)
>
> ...provides a comparison operator that treats two null values as
> the same.

The custom `equals(...)` function would possibly work like this:

1. Pass two expressions to the function that would be compared against each other.
2. The function would use some logic (TBD) that would return `true` if the two values are the same, and `false` if the two values are different.

   - Two nulls would be treated as being the same.
   - Nulls could be compared to non-nulls. For example, `'A' vs. null` would return `equals = false`, not unknown.

---

As a novice, that seems like an interesting idea.

With that said, I don't know how I'd create a function that would be capable accepting all the different datatypes that I might throw at it.

Normally, I'd write a function like this:

```
with function equals(v_text varchar2) return varchar2 --'SAME' or 'DIFFERENT'
```

But that only works for a single datatype, not multiple datatypes.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to create a function that accepts multiple datatypes? (with the `equals(...)` function idea in mind)

I imagine there might be a perfectly good reason why Oracle hasn't created a built-in function like that. I'm just trying to learn-by-experimenting & asking questions.

---

Related:

- [Idea: Support DECODE in PL/SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4500496/support-decode-in-pl-sql)
- [Idea: Support "IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM" syntax](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4500445/support-is-not-distinct-from-syntax)

Comment: While `DISTINCT` may not be a good choice for a name here, as there already exists a SQL keyword with that name (I'd choose something like EQUALS instead), this is a good question. You can write a function that accepts two nvarchar2 and compares these. Then all data that can be converted to nvarchar2 (and most is) can be passed to the function and the data gets converted implicitly. One problem with Oracle you have already noticed: there is no boolean type, so you must clumsily return 0 or 1 and check these codes then.

Comment: The problem with the above approach, though, is that the same datetime becomes something like '04.07.2022 16:45:31' if it's a `DATE`, but something like '2022-07-04 16:45:31,000000000' if it's a `TIMESTAMP`. In order to be able to match these, you'd really need a separate function. What you could do is write a PL/SQL package and write the same function in there multiple times with different parameters. (This is called function overloading.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks! Regarding built-in functions like DECODE that accept multiple different datatypes: Do you think that's what Oracle does — use function overloading?

Comment: I think that Oracle writes these functions in another programming language anyway. There are things that we cannot mimic in PL/SQL, especially a variable number of parameters as with `COALESCE`. But yeah, they'll use some kind of function overloading nonetheless, I guess. And yes, my favorite replacement for the missing SQL standard operator `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` in Oracle is `DECODE`: Our triggers have a lot of `DECODE(old.val, new.val, 'same', 'different') = 'different'` in their `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: Are you after a scalar function that operates on a pair of values or are you after an aggregation function that operates across all the rows of a column. The original version of the question asked for a `DISTINCT(...)` function that made it appear like it was a custom aggregation function but your edit makes it appear like you want a scalar function (which would be an entirely different solution).

Comment: @MTO Sorry for the confusion. I'm looking for a scalar function that operates on a pair of values.

Comment: You can probably write something using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68513994/1509264). I might have a go at it tomorrow.

Comment: It seems that "multiple" data types is less than what you are asking for. "Multiple" data types are supported easily, via overloading. What you seem to want, though, is "generic" data types; whenever "equality" is defined for a data type, you want the function to work for that data type. PL/SQL does not support generic data types. To clarify the ideas: same question as yours, but simplified - write a function that accepts one input of any data type, and returns TRUE if the input is non-NULL and FALSE if it is NULL. How do you **declare** such a function? That, by the way, is the big hurdle!

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean by "functionality... not available in Oracle". The functionality is available, it is just implemented differently. You yourself mentioned one implementation: `decode`. The other is to simply write `where a = b or a is null and b is null`. Note that in Oracle, unlike possibly other db products, you will not be able to use a FUNCTION (returning Boolean type) in a condition in SQL; while PL/SQL supports the Boolean data type, and the SQL Standard requires that SQL dialects support it, Oracle SQL does **not** support Boolean - it only allows "conditions".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom aggregation function to aggregate user-defined types that all inherit from a shared super-type.

Adapting [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643635/1509264):

If you have the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE parent_t IS OBJECT(
  a NUMBER
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE child_t UNDER parent_t(
  b NUMBER
);
```

and you want to aggregate them into a unique list into the type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE parent_tab IS TABLE OF parent_t;
/
```

Then you can declare the user-defined aggregation type:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ParentsTableUnion AS OBJECT(
  list parent_tab,

  STATIC FUNCTION is_equal(
    v_left  IN parent_t,
    v_right IN parent_t
  ) RETURN BOOLEAN,

  STATIC PROCEDURE merge(
    v_cur IN OUT parent_tab,
    v_new IN     parent_tab
  ),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT ParentsTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT ParentsTableUnion,
    value       IN     parent_t
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT ParentsTableUnion,
    returnValue    OUT parent_tab,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT ParentsTableUnion,
    ctx         IN OUT ParentsTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY ParentsTableUnion
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION is_equal(
    v_left  IN parent_t,
    v_right IN parent_t
  ) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF v_left.a = v_right.a
    OR (v_left.a IS NULL AND v_right.a IS NULL)
    THEN
      IF    v_left  IS NOT OF (child_t)
      AND   v_right IS NOT OF (child_t)
      THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
      ELSIF v_left  IS OF (child_t)
      AND   v_right IS OF (child_t)
      AND   (  TREAT(v_left AS child_t).b = TREAT(v_right AS child_t).b
            OR (TREAT(v_left AS child_t).b IS NULL AND TREAT(v_right AS child_t).b IS NULL)
            )
      THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
      END IF;      
    END IF;
    RETURN FALSE;
  END;
  
  STATIC PROCEDURE merge(
    v_cur IN OUT parent_tab,
    v_new IN     parent_tab
  )
  IS
    v_cnt PLS_INTEGER := v_cur.COUNT;
  BEGIN
    <<next_value>>
    FOR i IN 1 .. v_new.COUNT LOOP
      FOR j IN 1 .. v_cnt LOOP
        IF ParentsTableUnion.is_equal(v_new(i), v_cur(j))
        THEN
          CONTINUE next_value;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      v_cur.EXTEND(1);
      v_cur(v_cur.COUNT) := v_new(i);
    END LOOP;
  END;
  
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT ParentsTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := ParentsTableUnion( NULL );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT ParentsTableUnion,
    value       IN     parent_t
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSIF self.list IS NULL THEN
      self.list := parent_tab(value);
    ELSE
      ParentsTableUnion.merge(self.list, parent_tab(value));
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT ParentsTableUnion,
    returnValue    OUT parent_tab,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.list;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT ParentsTableUnion,
    ctx         IN OUT ParentsTableUnion
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    v_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    IF self.list IS NULL THEN
      self.list := ctx.list;
    ELSIF ctx.list IS NULL THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      ParentsTableUnion.merge(self.list, ctx.list);
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can wrap it in a user-defined aggregation function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION PARENT_T_UNION( list parent_t )
RETURN parent_tab
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING ParentsTableUnion;
/
```

Then, if you call it using:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT parent_t(1)  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT parent_t(2)  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT parent_t(1)  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT parent_t(3)  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child_t(1,1) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child_t(1,2) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child_t(2,1) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT child_t(1,1) FROM DUAL
)
SELECT u.a,
       TREAT(VALUE(u) AS child_t).b AS b
FROM   TABLE( ( SELECT PARENT_T_UNION(value) FROM data ) ) u
```

Then the output is:

> | A | B |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | *null* |
> | 2 | *null* |
> | 3 | *null* |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 1 | 2 |
> | 2 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1d6cfe40528997aef06e6578da95989e)*